# How to call Javascript function from Android without onPageFinished

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

There are a lot of answer but none of them work . All of them work with this funciotn:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:Test('Andrdoid-->Html')");
    }
});
```

but it work one time after load page in webview . we want use it during app is open by user.
some says use this line

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:Test('Andrdoid-->Html')");
```

without **onPageFinished** . but it cant help.
Javascript:

```
funtion Test(){
alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: I tested my code again , above code work but it cant  use **alert()**  in javascript . but can call all code of javascript with Java class

Answer (score 2):

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("Test('Andrdoid-->Html')", null);
```

**loadUrl** will reload the page and call onPageFinished() again.

You may try **evulateJavascript**.

**evaluateJavascript**, will run JavaScript asynchronously and avoid blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

well, the best way to communicate with webview is to make a bridge between the native application and web app,
check this [library](https://github.com/wendux/WebViewJavascriptBridge) it will help you to communicate with the web app.